# How to use Zend extension with PHP built-in server

Tags: php, server, zend-framework, local, php-extension

I am writing a toy [Zend extension](https://wiki.php.net/internals/extensions).

It works just fine when I run my script:

```sh
$ php -z /path/to/my/extension.so script.php
HELLO, TOY EXTENSION!
```

However, it does *not* work when I run the built-in development server:

```
$ php -z /path/to/my/extension.so -S localhost:8080 script.php
[Wed Aug 18 15:25:12 2021] PHP 7.4.21 Development Server (http://localhost:8080) started
```

As a sanity check, I tried making the extension write to a file instead of stdout, and still nothing happens.

Why isn't the local server using the extension? Naively it seems like this would Just Work. How can I get it to work? This would be very useful for testing and iterative development.

In case it's relevant, the hook where I put my `printf` is `zend_extension.activate`, although I have tried others as well (including `module_startup`).